# ЕХЕ-файл без зависимостей

Tags: windows, c++

Как мне сделать ЕХЕ файл в С++, чтобы он открывался без наличия С++ IDE на компьютере?

Comment: Надо с ним статически пролинковать все библиотеки.

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста объяснить более подробнее как это сделать

Comment: У тебя VS C++? Я в ней не очень большой спец. Подожди более конкретного ответа другого или сам покопайся.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас VS C++, тогда нужно клиентам устанавливать специальный пакет от майкрософта, который можно скачать [тут](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) (это для 32битных систем).
Если же у Вас С++ Builder, то нужно в настройках проекта снять галочку "use runtime packege" (или как она теперь называется).

Answer (score 1):

для VC необходимо в параметрах проекта выбрать CC++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library значение Multi-threaded или Multi-threaded Debug

Answer (score 0):

Для С++Builder снять галочку необходимо в двух местах. Еще и в управлении линкованием. Для запуска программы на компьютере разработчика этого делать не надо. Запустится и так: ОС знает, где находятся необходимые пакеты времени запуска.

Но, если Вы делаете для конкретного пользователя много программ, то имеет смысл установить ему на комп пакет необходимых RUN_TIME библиотек, т.к. размеры ЕХЕ-шников, сделанных STAND ALONE и с использованием RUN_TIME библиотек, различаются в десятки раз в пользу последних.